# How to implement a custom CompositeHealthContributor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I want to display the following Health-Information:

```
{
   "status":"UP", 
   "components": {
          "myHealthComposite": {
                "status":"UP",
                "components": {
                        "myFirstHealthIndicator": { "status":"UP" },
                        "mySecondHealthIndicator": { "status":"UP" }
                }
          }
    },
    "groups":[]
}
```

From the latest Spring Boot Actuator Documentation I should implement "myFirstHealthIndactor" and "mySecondHealthIndicator" with the "HealthIndicator"-Interface and composite them with the "CompositeHealthContributor"-Interface. But for "CompositeHealthContributor" I need an excample and in the Documentation I can not found something usefull for me.

Can someone help me with that, please?

Greetings

Edit:

**myFirstHealthIndicator**

```
@Component
public class MyFirstHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        return Health.up().build();
    }

}
```

**mySecondHealthIndicator**

```
@Component
public class MySecondHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        return Health.up().build();
    }

}
```

**myHealthComposite**

```
@Component
public class MyHealthComposite implements CompositeHealthContributor {

    @Override
    public HealthContributor getContributor(String name) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<NamedContributor<HealthContributor>> iterator() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: @QtRoS I can not post a great example because I need an advise how to implement a CompositeContributor but I hope you can work with my edited question.

Comment: _"From the latest Spring Boot Actuator Documentation"_

Can you please give us the source (so that we are on the same level)?

Answer (score 4):

A very simple and hard coded solution that outputs the expected.

Please remove the `@Component` annotation from **MyFirstHealthIndicator** and **MySecondHealthIndicator**. Otherwise, they are also listed as separate components.

**MyFirstHealthIndicator**

```java
public class MyFirstHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        return Health.up().build();
    }

}
```

**MySecondHealthIndicator**

```java
public class MySecondHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        return Health.up().build();
    }

}
```

**MyHealthComposite**

```java
@Component
public class MyHealthComposite implements CompositeHealthContributor {

    private Map<String, HealthContributor> contributors = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    MyHealthComposite() {
        this.contributors.put("myFirstHealthIndicator", new MyFirstHealthIndicator());
        this.contributors.put("mySecondHealthIndicator", new MySecondHealthIndicator());
    }

    @Override
    public HealthContributor getContributor(String name) {
        return contributors.get(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<NamedContributor<HealthContributor>> iterator() {
        return contributors.entrySet().stream()
                .map((entry) -> NamedContributor.of(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())).iterator();
    }
}
```

Please enable the `management.endpoint.health.show-components=always` in your `application.properties`.

The output looks like:

```json
{
  "status": "UP",
  "components": {
    "diskSpace": {
      "status": "UP"
    },
    "myHealthComposite": {
      "status": "UP",
      "components": {
        "myFirstHealthIndicator": {
          "status": "UP"
        },
        "mySecondHealthIndicator": {
          "status": "UP"
        }
      }
    },
    "ping": {
      "status": "UP"
    }
  }
}
```

However, this is not my solution, but is adopted from [BindersHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration from spring-cloud-stream](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/BindersHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.java) and adapted to the requirements.

Comment: What if I need to autowire something into `MyFirstHealthIndicator` or `MySecondHealthIndicator` and I don't want to display duplicated components.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to autowire something into your health indicators without duplicating health components:

**HealthIndicatorProvider**

```java
public interface HealthIndicatorProvider {
    String getName();
    HealthIndicator getHealthIndicator();
}
```

**MyFirstHealthIndicatorProvider**

```java
@Component
public class MyFirstHealthIndicatorProvider implements HealthIndicatorProvider {
    private final SomethingToAutowire1 somethingToAutoWire1;

    public MyFirstHealthIndicatorProvider(SomethingToAutowire1 somethingToAutoWire1) {
        this.somethingToAutoWire1 = somethingToAutoWire1;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "myFirstHealthIndicator";
    }

    public HealthIndicator getHealthIndicator() {
        return new HealthIndicator() {
            @Override
            public Health health() {
                return Health.up().build();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**MySecondHealthIndicatorProvider**

```java
@Component
public class MySecondHealthIndicatorProvider implements HealthIndicatorProvider {
    private final SomethingToAutowire2 somethingToAutoWire2;

    public MySecondHealthIndicatorProvider(SomethingToAutowire2 somethingToAutoWire2) {
        this.somethingToAutoWire2 = somethingToAutoWire2;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "mySecondHealthIndicator";
    }

    public HealthIndicator getHealthIndicator() {
        return new HealthIndicator() {
            @Override
            public Health health() {
                return Health.up().build();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**MyCompositeHealthConfig**

```java
@Configuration
public class MyCompositeHealthConfig {

    @Bean
    public CompositeHealthContributor myHealthComposite(List<HealthIndicatorProvider> healthIndicatorProviders) {
        return CompositeHealthContributor.fromMap(
                healthIndicatorProviders.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        HealthIndicatorProvider::getName,
                        HealthIndicatorProvider::getHealthIndicator
                ))
        );
    }

}
```